# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTMl' of null in 3rd line of code

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I cannot figure out what is wrong here.

```
for ( var i = 0; i< choices.length; i++) {
        element = document.getElementById("choice" + i);
        element.innerHTMl = choices[i];
        Guess ("btn" + i, choices[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Also it should be innerHTML, not innerHTMl (last letter is lowercase in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Its innerHTML and you need to make sure the element exists.

```
for ( var i = 0; i< choices.length; i++) {
    element = document.getElementById("choice" + i);
    if( element ) {
        element.innerHTMl = choices[i];
        Guess ("btn" + i, choices[i]);
    } 
}
```